# Why am I not logged in to all of my communities when I log into StackExchange?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

I noticed that after I log into SE I am automatically logged into *most* of the communities that I am a member of, but not all. Ask Ubuntu, for example, requires me to sign in again, but doesn't have the option to simply use my SE credentials. I'm not sure if there is something I missed, or some trick to logging in that would actually log me in to all of my communities.

Basically, I go to my communities page, select Ask Ubuntu, and I'm taken to my user profile, but I'm not logged in. Therefore, it would seem that the profiles are linked, so why not log me in to all communities associated with my SE profile?

Comment: Your browser is configured to block third-party cookies, which makes it fail for sites hosted on different domains, such as Ask Ubuntu. See [Login required moving to Super User on iPad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314666/login-required-moving-to-super-user-on-ipad)

Comment: @Sonic Thank You! This whole time I've been thinking I set my account up wrong or something silly like that.

Comment: You can click "That solved my problem" to indicate that your issue was resolved by that post.