# Merging SO and SE accounts

Tags: support, login

I always have to log in again if I'm going from any SE website to SO.
How can I merge my SO and SE accounts so that I don't have to log in twice?

Comment: @RobertLongson for some odd reason it says  the accounts are already merged, but they're not

Comment: This is happening because your browser is restricting third-party cookies, which are necessary for the login mechanism to work for sites that are hosted on different domains. See my answer to [Login required moving to Super User on iPad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314666/login-required-moving-to-super-user-on-ipad)

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog thank you!