# How do I create an account on Super User using this account?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I've been able to sign up to different Stack Exchange sites by "linking" with my existing account, but I can't seem to do this for Super User.

I don't want to end up with different accounts and passwords and all the rest of it.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

(EDIT: Logging out and back in fixed it, but the answer still applies.)

Comment: Related/dupe if you're on iOS https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314666/398063

Comment: Do you remember what the last time was you logged in and visited Super user? It could be that your cookies had expired.

Comment: @rene I'd never logged into to SU before. I may have visited the odd page before. However, I was technically still logged in to my other SE sites, but something may have gone off.

Comment: Okay, that could explain why logging out and back in fixed it, you have received new browser cookies for super user and all other SE domains by doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join other Stack Exchange community, when you are already logged-in.

1. Click on the Stack Exchange icon in the top bar, once the pop up is open, scroll down to find the "More Stack Exchange Communities" text box. Enter Super User in the text box and from the list click the link to open the superuser.com

   [image]
2. Now you can see the "Join the Community" button, clicking on the you can see another window

   [image]
3. Clicking on the "Confirm new account" will create a user account in Super User with your current credentials

   [image]

Comment: I don't get the "Join This Community" button. I just get FaceBook or email login options. I was able to join this group, but not super user.

Comment: @benwiggy Can you able to access this URL to create an account in the Super User https://superuser.com/users/join?ssrc=hero&returnurl=https://superuser.com/

Comment: Fixed it: Logged out and back in, and then I could join.

Comment: Doesn't work. It's in different domain, so apparently the cookies don't recognize me being logged eg. here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work a bit different now then explained in the other answers (I can't comment on that one yet, since I am new on this community (having just used my Stack Overflow account to join here)). There does not seem to be a “Join this Community” button anywhere anymore.

But, when clicking the above-mentioned Stack Exchange icon in the top bar in a Stack Exchange site you are logged into, you see "Your communities" (above the "More Stack Exchange communities" part which the previous answers tried to use). You can press *edit* on the right and search for other communities (e.g. Super user). Once you see the one you want, you can *add* it and *Save*.

Now, when you change to this community, you will still have to log in first. But you can use your existing credentials from the community that you used to log into before (e.g. from Stack Overflow). You will then get the same message mentioned above, about linking the account. You have to confirm this.