# Notification Bar (podcast, etc.) should be dismissed on sites where you don't have an account

Tags: bug, status-completed, notification-bar

Opening bug report for:

> [Ooh, good point. We can actually fix that, though. Would you mind writing up a separate bug report for that, please? – Adam Lear♦︎](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334137/dismiss-the-meet-the-overflow-and-podcast-episode-banners-network-wide/337288#comment1121011_337288)

1. Have an account on any Stack Exchange site (and are thus signed in across the network).
2. Dismiss the top banner advertising the Podcast by clicking the `X`.
3. Visit another site, where you also have an account.
4. Banner ***is*** also dismissed there (after a few minutes).

   - [Dismiss the "Meet The Overflow" and Podcast Episode banners network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334137/dismiss-the-meet-the-overflow-and-podcast-episode-banners-network-wide)
5. Click a Hot Network Question and visit *a site that you haven't joined.*

[image]

Podcast banner is **still shown** on no-account sites.

Comment: I imagine that even after this gets fixed, this will continue to be an issue for other sites that are on domains other than stackexchange.com, on browsers that block cross-site cookies (and thus [don't recognize that you're logged in to the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314666/login-required-moving-to-super-user-on-ipad).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We should now correctly recognize your network account id even if you don't have a profile on the site you're visiting - provided, as [Sonic points out in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337356/notification-bar-podcast-etc-should-be-dismissed-on-sites-where-you-dont-ha#comment1121035_337356), we know who you are in the first place. Still, better than nothing. At the very least, dismissing the banner on a *.stackexchange.com site will cover all of the Q&A sites rooted at that domain, which is the majority of our site network.