# How do I get Askubuntu.com to recognize the fact that i'm already logged-in on Stackexchange?

Tags: support, login, askubuntu, shared-accounts

I have a profile on AskUbuntu.com which is recognized on my StackEchange profile (https://askubuntu.com/users/780824/camion). I have already asked and answered questions there. But even though I'm logged in stack exchange, Askubuntu does not see me as logged in. I have a long history of problems with that and though I have been able to access it up to end 2018, and I don't understand why it can't do it anymore.

I have seen multiple questions about similar problems, but they all are older than 2018 and do not really helped me solve it. Amongst other, they proposed to log in with the same user and password, but using the same user and password on two different log in systems is a security hole. either your credential cookies are shared, or one should use different logging info.

EDIT: it has been suggested to deactivate third party cookies blocking, but I do not want to ruin my browser's tracking protection.

Comment: Do you have third-party cookies disabled (lots of people do)? If so, that's why. With a different domain, they have different cookies, so we don't keep you logged in

Comment: As Catija mentions, this is because your browser is blocking cross-site (third-party) cookies. This is explained in detail at [Login required moving to Super User on iPad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314666/login-required-moving-to-super-user-on-ipad)

Comment: OK. I tried to deactivate firefox's extended tracking protection on stackexchange.com, askubuntu.com and meta.askubuntu.com. Then I logged out and back in on stackexchange.com and refreshed the askubuntu pages and it solved the problem. Thank you; Would you want to make it an answer so that i can accept it, do shall I do it by myself ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Catija and Sonic the Curiouser Hedgehog pointed that the problem arose from the third party blocking.

Since I do not want to remove it entirely, I deactivated firefox's extended tracking protection on stackexchange.com, askubuntu.com and meta.askubuntu.com (by clicking on the little shield left to the URLs).

Then I logged out and back in on stackexchange.com and refreshed the askubuntu pages and it solved the problem.