# I keep getting the privacy pop-up windows when browsing SE on iOS

Tags: bug, popups, cookies, ios, mobile-chrome

I keep getting the privacy pop-up windows when browsing SE with Chrome on my iPhone (iOS 15):

[image]

I don't think that's intended, so I'm tagging that as a bug. Feel free to retag as support if I missed something.

Comment: Possibly [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314666/163188).